# How to delete records in the table which are repeated?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi Here i came across a situation in which by mistakenly Without dropping the table i have run the batch file of the table which consists of some insert statements in detail

I have a table like alert_priority consists of records like

```
Id  priority_name
---  --------------
1     P0
2     P1
3     P2
```

and now by mistakenly without dropping **alert_priority** i have executed script file of the table which consists of some insert statements and now after executing the script my records in the table are like

```
Id  priority_name
---  --------------
1     P0
2     P1
3     P2
1     P0
2     P1
3     P2
```

Now i want to delete the records which are extra(records after Id 3) and i should have all the records which are present before i have executed the script file.

Although i have an option to drop the table and execute the script file once again, I wanted to know is there any way which we can do through sql query

 **I have no primay keys in the table**

Comment: If you had a primary key on ID, this wouldn't have happened in the first place...unique constraints are your friend. :)

Comment: There are several options I can think of.  One you could generate a script for the table AND the data (assuming you don't have an obscene amount), and then you can just cut out the inserts you don't need (this takes about 30 seconds if you're using SSMS).  truncate table and execute new script.  Or you could select the top X amount (however many records there really are), insert them into a temporary table, drop table and re-create, and copy back over.

Comment: @John Woo, howeverr, there is no marked answer to the question you refer to

Comment: @aviad: This is most likely a mindlessly copy-pasted question from a completely unrelated user. We get that fairly often, and it's a mystery why people do this at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First , consider setting your `ID` fields as AI (auto increasment) and even PK (Primary Key).

In order to remove those duplicated rows , we will create a new table and will move all
those duplicated rows to it.
After that , drop that table.

> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bad_temp AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM alert_priority

Answer (score 1):

you can copy all unique records into a new table, then delete the old table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

Comment: They are not distinct, look at the ID column.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server it would be easy using ROW_NUMBER, but alas MySQL doesn't have a function like that :-(

Best way to solve it would be as follows:

- Create a new table identical in structure to the first, but with no
  data.
- Use the query: `INSERT INTO name_of_new_table SELECT DISTINCT * FROM name_of_old_table`
- Drop the old table
- Rename the new table to whatever the old table was called.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl(id int AUTO_INCREMENT,priority_name);

INSERT INTO new_tbl
select priority_name from old_tbl group by priority_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

To just delete the duplicate new rows and leave the old ones in place (on the basis that I assume there are already other tables whose rows refer to the original rows):-

```
DELETE FROM alert_priority
WHERE Id IN (SELECT MaxId
FROM (SELECT priority_name, MAX(Id) AS MaxId, COUNT(Id)  AS CountId
FROM alert_priority
GROUP BY priority_name
HAVING CountId > 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you all records that you want to keep:

```
SELECT min(id)
FROM alert_priority
GROUP BY priority_name
HAVING count(*) > 1
    OR min(id) = max(id)
```

To remove all duplicates, run this query:

```
DELETE FROM alert_priority
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM alert_priority
    GROUP BY priority_name
    HAVING count(*) > 1
        OR min(id) = max(id)
)
```