# How to delete records in the table which are repeated?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete records in the table which are repeated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891402/how-to-delete-records-in-the-table-which-are-repeated)

Hi Here i came across a situation in which by mistakenly Without dropping the table i have run the batch file of the table which consists of some insert statements in detail

I have a table like alert_priority consists of records like

```
Id  priority_name
---  --------------
1     P0
2     P1
3     P2
```

and now by mistakenly without dropping alert_priority i have executed script file of the table which consists of some insert statements and now after executing the script my records in the table are like

```
Id  priority_name
---  --------------
1     P0
2     P1
3     P2
1     P0
2     P1
3     P2
```

Now i want to delete the records which are extra(records after Id 3) and i should have all the records which are present before i have executed the script file.

Although i have an option to drop the table and execute the script file once again, I wanted to know is there any way which we can do through sql query 
I have no primay keys in the table